# How to animate adding and removing element to Layout in QML?

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I want to animate adding and removing of TextField in ColumnLayout. Basically I want to animate like this:- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videos/viewtransitions-basic.mp4

Comment: That is a ListView, which has the corresponding transitions. Do you specifically want a ColumnLayout?

Comment: @Amfasis yes. I have Login page which uses ColumnLayout in which I want to animate the addition/removal of extra TextFields when state changes.

Comment: `ColumnLayout` has no transitions, so you cannot add animation. Use `ListView` instead, as @Amfasis already said. It looks the same and has transitions to animate what you want.

Comment: @folibis can you add an arbritary item to the ListView, which will also use the transitions?

Answer (score 3):

As a ColumnLayout uses the `implicitHeight` to position the items, you can add an animation to that to create the sliding effect. I used a wrapping `Item` to preserve the `implicitHeight` of the `TextField` itself. It may not look perfect, but I don't think you cannot get that much further

```
Item {

    visible: your_property_here

    implicitHeight: visible ? text.implicitHeight : 0
    Behavior on implicitHeight { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }

    TextField {
        id: text
        anchors.fill: parent

        scale: parent.visible ? 1 : 0.2
        Behavior on scale { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found effective answer. Until then I'm using column as workaround

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {

    id: page_root

    component ETextField : TextField {
        width: root.width/2
    }


    state: "LOGIN"

    Column {

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        ETextField {
            id:host
            placeholderText: "Host e.g:- exam.server.com:8080"
        }

        ETextField {
            id:uane
            placeholderText: "Username"
        }

        ETextField {
            id: passwd
            placeholderText: "Password"
        }

        ETextField {
            id: confirm_passwd
            placeholderText: "Confirm Password"
        }

        RowLayout {
            Button {
                id: submit
                text: "Login"
            }
            Button {
                id: change_state
                text: "Register Instead"
                onClicked:  page_root.state = page_root.state === "LOGIN" ? "REGISTER" : "LOGIN"
            }
        }
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "LOGIN"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: confirm_passwd
                height: passwd.height

            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: change_state
                text : "Register Instead"
            }
        },
        State {
            name: "REGISTER"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: confirm_passwd
                height: 0
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: change_state
                text : "Login Instead"
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "LOGIN"
            to: "REGISTER"
            NumberAnimation {
                target: confirm_passwd
                property : "height"
                duration: 100
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "REGISTER"
            to: "LOGIN"
            NumberAnimation {
                target: confirm_passwd
                property : "height"
                duration: 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```